# Breakup csv in column of one table for insert into new table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

How do I split values that look like this:
'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287'

into this:

```
value1    value2
some      1234
dumb      4321
thing     6534
someone   65432
did       43287
```

for insertion into a new table.

The following code shows something that 'looks' like I'm trying to achieve. I've been working on this for about a day now pulling my hair out.

I've also included table and function definitions with a couple of rows of data to illustrate what I'm looking to achieve.

```
-- Shamelessly copied this function from the CTE String Split here: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitStrings -- Just being trying to be complete so adding this function since it is not an mssql built-in
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @Items TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(4000))
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ll INT = LEN(@List) + 1, @ld INT = LEN(@Delimiter);

   WITH a AS
   (
       SELECT
           [start] = 1,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll),
           [value] = SUBSTRING(@List, 1, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll) - 1)
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
           [start] = CONVERT(INT, [end]) + @ld,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll),
           [value] = SUBSTRING(@List, [end] + @ld, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll)-[end]-@ld)
       FROM a
       WHERE [end] < @ll
   )
   INSERT @Items SELECT [value]
   FROM a
   WHERE LEN([value]) > 0
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

   RETURN;
END
GO

-- Primary table where the messed up data currently resides
create table dbo.things
(
    Id int identity(1,1) not null,
    User int not null,
    Values varchar(256)
)
-- This is the bad data
insert into things(USER,Values) values
{100,'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287'},
{101,'this:31234,is:43221,so wrong:65482'}

-- This is where the split up data will reside in the future
create table dbo.propertableforvalues
(
        ThingId int not null,
        ValueID int not null,
    ValueName varchar(256) not null
)

-- This doesn't come close to working, but 'looks' like what I'm trying to achieve
insert into dbo.propertableforvalues
select
(
    select 
        t.Id,
        outerSplit.Name,
        outerSplit.ValueId
    from 
        (select -- one 'things' record should create n rows based on the number of items in the comma split of the 'Values' string
            innerT.Name,
                        innerT.ValueId
         from 
                        dbo.splitStrings(
                        (select
                            ValueId,
                            ValueName
                        from
                                dbo.splitStrings(t.Values, ',') -- Split first based on the comma
                                    , ':')) as innerSplit                               -- Split a second time on the colon
        ) as outerSplit
)
from
    things t
where
    t.Values is not null
    and t.Values <> ''
```

For each record in 'things' the 'Values' column should be split twice. The first split gives the data for the new records. That data needs to be split one more time to get the individual fields.

I would prefer to stay away from cursors, I have thousands of records to update.

**EDIT**

I was not as clear as I should have been in what I was expecting but you guys had some great ideas.  My final result should look like the following for insert into the new table. Thanks for all your help so far!

```
ID  Item         Value
1   some         1234
1   dumb         4321
1   thing        6534
1   someone      65432
1   did          43287
2   this         31234
2   is           43221
2   so wrong     65482
```

Answer (score 4):

In such cases I prefer this approach:

This is your string

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(100)='some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287';
```

Some replacements transform this string into a XML:

```
SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT @csv AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</y></x><x><y>'),':','</y><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML);
```

This is the result, which we can query with XML methods.

```
<x>
  <y>some</y>
  <y>1234</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>dumb</y>
  <y>4321</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>thing</y>
  <y>6534</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>someone</y>
  <y>65432</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>did</y>
  <y>43287</y>
</x>
```

Try it out:

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(100)='some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287';

SELECT x.value('y[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Item
      ,x.value('y[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Value]
FROM (SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT @csv AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</y></x><x><y>'),':','</y><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)) t(casted)
CROSS APPLY t.casted.nodes('/x') A(x);
```

### UPDATE

The same with table data

```
DECLARE @things TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1) not null,
    [User] int not null,
    [Values] varchar(256)
)
insert into @things([USER],[Values]) values
(100,'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287'),
(101,'this:31234,is:43221,so wrong:65482');

SELECT t.Id
      ,t.[User] 
      ,x.value('y[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Item
      ,x.value('y[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Value]
FROM @things t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT t.[Values] AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</y></x><x><y>'),':','</y><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)) A(casted)
CROSS APPLY A.casted.nodes('/x') B(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is convert your string into XML and then simply parse the XML

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287'


Declare @XML xml = '<row '+replace(replace(@S,',','" '),':','="')+'"/>'

Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
 From  @XML.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
```

**Returns**

```
Item    Value
some    1234
dumb    4321
thing   6534
someone 65432
did     43287
```

**Edit - Notice data is in a table**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,someone:65432,did:43287')
,(2,'aaa:111,bbb:222,ccc:333,ddd:444,eee:555')


Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( try_convert(xml,'<row '+replace(replace(SomeCol,',','" '),':','="')+'"/>'))
             ) B(xmlData) 
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Item    Value
1   some    1234
1   dumb    4321
1   thing   6534
1   someone 65432
1   did     43287
2   aaa     111
2   bbb     222
2   ccc     333
2   ddd     444
2   eee     555
```

Comment: Just one hint: This approach might get in troubles, if the Items are not valid as attribute names or if the string might include forbidden characters... (like the "so wrong" in the second example...)

Comment: John, did you see the provided test data? Don't know about the OP's real world data, but *101,'this:31234,is:43221,so wrong:65482'* would break due to the blank in "so wrong"...

Comment: @Shnugo It feels like a JSON object.  But you are right.  If "so wrong" it would fail.

Comment: True... This is tagged with `sql-server-2012`  - no JSON-support regrettfully... Still a very slick approach ;-)

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks but your X/Y is safer

Comment: I should have put the 'so wrong' data in the first string.  Sorry about that.  This is the closest to what I'm looking for though and I appreciate you taking your solution to the final conclusion!

Answer (score 1):

As one of the options, I am gonna post no-xml method of doing the same task, not undermining earlier given answers.

In order for this method to work, @CSV string must be enclosed with delimiters at the beginning and ending:

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(8000) = 'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,some one:65432,did:43287'

SET @csv = ',' + @csv + ','
```

First, build a Numbers cte (also called *Tally*):

```
-- Build 10000 numbers.
;WITH
TENS (N)      AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0),
THOUSANDS (N) AS (SELECT 1
                FROM TENS t1
                     CROSS JOIN TENS t2
                     CROSS JOIN TENS t3),
TALLY (N)     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
                FROM THOUSANDS)
```

and find the indexes of separator(delimiter) which is a *','* in our case.

```
SELECT N
FROM TALLY
WHERE SUBSTRING(@csv,N,1) = ','
```

Then use SUBSTRING and slice the CSV with index value of delimiter to get the first part, then repeat the same thing with new delimiter which is ***':'***

```
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(8000) = 'some:1234,dumb:4321,thing:6534,some one:65432,did:43287'

SET @csv = ',' + @csv + ','

-- Build 10000 numbers.
;WITH
TENS (N)      AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0),
THOUSANDS (N) AS (SELECT 1
                FROM TENS t1
                     CROSS JOIN TENS t2
                     CROSS JOIN TENS t3),
TALLY (N)     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
                FROM THOUSANDS)
--Split CSV values into columns
,SPLITTED AS (
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@csv,N+1,CHARINDEX(',',@csv,N+1)-N-1) AS ColName
            FROM TALLY
            WHERE N < LEN(@csv) AND SUBSTRING(@csv,N,1) = ','  )

--Split column values further into as multiple columns
SELECT Part1 = SUBSTRING(ColName,1,CHARINDEX(':', ColName,1)-1),
       Part2 = SUBSTRING(ColName,CHARINDEX(':', ColName,1)+1,LEN(ColName))
FROM SPLITTED
```